# Why do I have an unreachable statement? (JAVA)

Tags: java

```
/*
Eika Roy
Period 2
C5_est_PartB_P2
*/

public class PatrioticDay {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        int starCount = 0;
        
        //rows (horizontal)
        for(int i = 1; 1 < 10; i++) {
            
            //colums (vertical)
            for(int j = 1; j < 12; j++){
                
                //print a star / print a space 
                if(i == j){
                    System.out.print(" * ");
                    starCount++;
                }else if((i % 2 !=0 && j % 2 != 0) || (1 % 2 == 0 && j % 2 == 0)){
                    System.out.print(" * ");
                    starCount++;
                }else{
                    System.out.print("  ");
                }
            }
            
            System.out.println("");
            
        }
        
        System.out.println("\nThe Star Count: " + starCount);
        System.out.println("USA, USA, USA! ");
    }    
}
```

The second to last system.out.println is the unreachable statement

Comment: Why do you have `1 % 2 == 0`?

Comment: Look at this statement very closely: `for(int i = 1; 1 < 10; i++)`

Comment: I think you've used `1` where you meant `i` in a couple of places.

Answer (score 2):

In your outer for loop you have 1<10 in the condition, which is always true, so its an infinite loop. I think you mean to put i<10